# How to load props asynchronously for functional component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to speed up my application and in order to do this, I am lazy loading some components. One of my functional component loads from a .json file and it would be nice to lazy load it as well, but I am not sure how to do it. My code currently looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Presentation from "../Presentation";

const data = () => import("../assets/sample.json");

const Finder = (props) => {

    const {prop1} = props;

    return ( <Presentation data={data} selection={prop1} /> );
};

export default Presentation;
```

When trying to render the Presentation component, it fails with an error (data undefined). How could I lazy load the json file? Is it possible using the react-loadable library? Thanks!

Comment: use `React.lazy` or `Suspense`, check the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) for more details.

Comment: using const data = React.lazy(() => import("../assets/sample.json"), gives me the same error.

Comment: can you show the error message?

Comment: The error message comes from the Presentation component saying that data is undefined. Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.